# IEWC Treeview refreshing to top of page on click

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-webcontrol

I am using an IEWC webcontrol in ASPX/C# page and whenever a treeview element is clicked, it will refresh to the top of the page. Is there any way to stop this?
It now works fine in IE with the addition of Autopostback and Viewstate set to True. Just not in Chrome.
(Note: I am well aware that IE web controls were never meant to work 100% outside IE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by adding in a piece of jQUery that searches for the element's parent ID and removes the HREF on the nodes.
Alternatively, you can set a session parameter that remembers the `scrollX` and re-set this on page load